# Where does "kubectl edit" pick env values from?

Tags: kubectl

I have a Kubernetes deployment container with

```
          env:
            - name: AWS_REGION
              value: ${AWS_REGION_1}
```

and no config map referenced.

I do

```
kubectl edit deployment my_deployment_1
```

and change the configuration to

```
          env:
            - name: AWS_REGION
              value: ${AWS_REGION_2}
```

Where does Kubernetes pick value of **AWS_REGION_2** from ?

Comment: could you elaborate your specific environment and deployment setup so that we can come to know where the value is coming from and it is easy to find the appropriate solution?

Comment: I currently work with EKS. But this question applies to any Kubernetes cluster. Where does the env values get picked from when there is no config map referenced ? Does it pick from the envs from terminal session I have logged in ?